# error while loading a gzip mysql table file to my local mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I dumped a file with gzip from remote server, this way:

```
mysqldump -uuser -h host_address -ppassword --quick --compress --max_allowed_packet=512M db_name table_name | gzip  > my_dmp.sql.gz
```

and reloaded it locally, this way:

```
gunzip < my_dmp.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -h 127.0.0.1 --quick --compress --max_allowed_packet=512M DatabaseName
```

it worked before, and its still working, but now in the middle of loading it I get this error:

> gunzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line
>    276: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>    near ''20' at line 1

I dont really understand, cause if there is an issue in the file how come when I go to the table locally it was created with 1.5m records out of 4m

any suggestions?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your gzip file is corrupt. Try just doing a `gunzip my_dmp.sql.gz` and see if it runs fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info:

> gunzip: (stdin): unexpected end of file

Your compressed file is not OK. To be sure you can try something like:

```
gzip -dc my_dmp.sql.gz >/dev/null
```

If this command return you a error this confirm it.